# "unlock" R6 class only durring initialize

Tags: r, oop, r6

I want to dynamically add methods to an `R6` class, but only during `initialize()`. For this I must set `lock_objects` to `FALSE`. Is there a not-to-hacky way to lock the object again at the end of `initialize()`?